# Get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend' error message while trying to retrieve dictionary keys into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.8

I'm using `Python 3.8.0` and I try to write a function which extracts all the keys of nested dictionaries and gathers the result in a list. Here is an example:

```
mydict = {"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":{"k4":"v4","k5":{"k6":{"k7":"v7","k8":"v8"}}}}
```

What I expect as the output is:

```
[k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k7, k8]
```

Here is a recursive function that I've defined :

```
def extract_dict_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        result = []
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                result.append(k).extend(extract_dict_keys(v))
            else:
                result.append(k)
        return result
    else:
        [None]
```

But when I call `extract_dict_keys(mydict)` I get the following error message:

```
>>> extract_dict_keys(mydict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in extract_dict_keys
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
>>>
```

Could you kindly indicate what I misunderstand? I don't see the problem.

Comment: `append()` does not return anything; you can't chain off it. Maybe `result.extend([k] + extract_dict_keys(v))` would be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result.append(k)` returns `None` it only adds k to end of the list

to fix it you can split it to two lines

```
result.append(k)
result.extend(extract_dict_keys(v))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As the others answers have pointed out, `append` returns `None`, so you cannot do `result.append(k).extend(extract_dict_keys(v))`, since that extends a `NoneType`, not a list. You need to first add the key, then continue the recursion.

An easy way would be to add the key before entering the `if` to check if the value is of type `dict`:

```
mydict = {"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":{"k4":"v4","k5":{"k6":{"k7":"v7","k8":"v8"}}}}

def extract_dict_keys(d):
    keys = []

    for k, v in d.items():
        keys.append(k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            keys.extend(extract_dict_keys(v))

    return keys

print(extract_dict_keys(mydict))
# ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'k8']
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the error is from calling `extend()` on the result of `append()`, which is `None`.

It's often nicer to code this sort of recursion with a generator. This has several benefits: you don't need to maintain the inner state, you save memory, and the code is simpler:

```
mydict = {"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2", "k3":{"k4":"v4","k5":{"k6":{"k7":"v7","k8":"v8"}}}}

def extract_dict_keys(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return
    for k, v in d.items():
        yield k
        yield from extract_dict_keys(v)

list(extract_dict_keys(mydict))
# ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'k8']
```

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know that it was possible to write successively two times the yield statement because I thought that yield would act like return excepts that it memorizes the last call (= the last returned value). Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Append returns None so you need to separate the code like below:

```
def extract_dict_keys(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        result = []
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                result.append(k).
                result.extend(extract_dict_keys(v))
            else:
                result.append(k)
        return result
    else:
        [None]
```